# How do we upload lambda function .zip directly from CLI?

Tags: go, aws-lambda, redis, amazon-elasticache

I use Ubuntu and have this Golang lambda function with Redis. Already zipped and uploaded it. But I still need to develop it further.

Every time I made changes and want to see the logs in CloudWatch... It seems that I need to do the steps over and over.

code -> build main.go -> zipped -> upload it -> trigger the function -> see the logs

ineffective.

is there a way to simplify the steps?

is it possible to upload it through CLI?

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can upload using the cli:

```
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name  my-function \
    --zip-file fileb://my-function.zip
```

you can see [this particular example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html#examples) in the docs.

The other steps should be pretty easy to automate with a simple script.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone requiring to also trigger the deploy locally, but instead using an S3 object:

```bash
aws lambda update-function-code \
    --function-name "my-lambda-function" \
    --s3-bucket "<bucket>" \
    --s3-key "<object key>"
```

Here's how to build and upload to S3 using the [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html):

```
sam build
sam package --s3-bucket "<bucket>"
```